# Merge branch '2.8' into '3.2'?

Tags: git, symfony

I know and I practice gitflow. I was studying how Symfony manages its Github repository, then I started GitKraken to get a nice branches rendering

[image]

Something totally freaked me out, the commit "Merge branch '2.8' into '3.2'". How is this even semantically possible ? It perceive it as a non-sense because these versions are incompatible (http://semver.org/).
Can some explain me this?

Comment: If you scroll down, you'll see another commit bearing the same description.  I'm not sure there is any cause for alarm here, this could just be someone syncing up the `2.8` branch with the `3.2` branch by doing mutual merge commits.

Comment: Can you explain more ? I don't really understand, thank you

Comment: I don't really understand either, this is just speculation, the message may not reflect what it even says.  If the `3.2` branch had a merge commit from someone else merging `2.8` into it, and then `3.2` got merged into your main branch whose diagram you showed above, then it could explain why that particular commit message appears the way it does.

Comment: Hmm, so do you agree that .. semantically according to http://semver.org/ it is a non sense to merge a 2.8 into 3.2 ? 
I could have understood if they merged a 2.7 into 2.8, but 2.8 into 3.2 ...

Comment: This could have happened for so many reasons, bugfix, hotfix, etc.

Comment: I understand what you say, but different major versions are API incompatible, so how merging these could not break code base implying lot and lot of conflicts, regressions, etc ?

Comment: If you have two branches `2.8` and `3.2`, then `git checkout 3.2;git merge 2.8` makes it. If you want to know why to make a such merge, ask the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> semantically according to semver.org it is a non sense to merge a 2.8 into 3.2 ?

First, Git is not concerned *at all* with semver: it knowns how to merge two branches, no matter their name.

Second, you need to know what a 2.8 branch means. It can mean a "maintenance or hotfix" branch, where additional fixes commit were made. Those fixes might be required in the current 3.2 release. This is typical of a product which has to maintained multiple releases  currently in production.

> but different major versions are API incompatible, so how merging these could not break code base implying lot and lot of conflicts, regressions, etc ?

Because the merge can be a partial one: before completing the merge, you can drop/reset any part you don't want, and keep only the fixes you want.

If you consider [merge commit cfc6baf](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/cfc6bafed22d5eb8915c03df9d1c143a7a3700c0) and [merge commit 6516a20](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/6516a20e11e71796f278faa933ca76906149530b), that seems to be the case: only some tests were affected.

Comment: Ok, the thing that others didn't talk about is partial merges. Thank you.

Comment: @NathanVss Don't forget that a merge can only serve as a "marker": any subsequent merge from one branch to the other will ignore any commit older than the previous merge, so the next merges will be limited to the small evolution that might be needed in the other branch too.